# Display certain filtered search results

Tags: javascript

I have tracks and places being pushed into the search results.  I want to only show tracks.  The `_type` of a place is `"system.place"` and a track is `"system.tracking"`.  Even though I have an if statement to check each result from the search it still displays all results.  Any input will be helpful.

```
 $scope.trackSearchChanged = function(searchText) {
  if (searchText == '') {
    $scope.trackSearchResults = [];
  }
  else {
    Service.typeAheadSearch(searchText, 20).then(function (response) {
      angular.forEach(response.results, function (track, index) {
        if (track._type != "system.place") {
          $scope.trackSearchResults = response.results;
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your `forEach` function to filter anything, you'll have to create a second array to push your desired values into.

```
Service.typeAheadSearch(searchText, 20).then(function (response) {
  var places = [];
  angular.forEach(response.results, function (track, index) {
    if (track._type != "system.place") {
      places.push(track);
    }
  });
  $scope.trackSearchResults = places;
});
```

Comment: That fixed the issue.  That was a simple fix.  Thanks!